# Form suddenly won't work in Access 2007 after editing in Access 2013

Tags: database, ms-access

At work, I use Access 2007.  I often bring home projects to complete or edit some features in Access 2013.  I've never had a problem, until recently.  I have a form that displays in datasheet mode.  It was originally designed in 2007.  I believe all I did was resize the form.  I don't even recall changing any of the VBA.  When I brought it to work, I got an 'Unrecognized Database Format Error'.  Reading up on this, I found that I could get it to work open a blank database in 2010 and import the objects.  Still no go.

I tried something that gets me a step further - I had some links to Excel spreadsheets that no longer exist, so I deleted those links and now it opens - That's how I got the information that it is the form with the datasheet format causing the error.  I've been combing through trying to see what features I may have automatically inherited in Access 2013, but I can't imagine what they are.

I figured I would compile the code, but when I look at the modules, there are a whole bunch of them and none of them will open. 
 Any suggestions?

Comment: That is not an unusual occurrence. It is always best to develop in the earliest version of Access that will be used. When trying to go backwards, some minor change could cause a change in the file format when saved, especially if a C&R was done.

Comment: None of the buttons on the forms work. It's just a museum and none of my code is there either.

Answer (score 0):

A list of features that are not available in Microsoft Access 2007 can be viewed at the following link:

[Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/dn602608(v=office.14).aspx)

The hardest one I can remember trying to track down was the empty cell on a form or report as these are not supported in Microsoft Access 2007.